# Setting the value of C string with format specifier

Tags: c, string

Whenever I need to assign to a string and I have some word (called `variedinput`) that is assigned via standard input, socket, etc, I do something like

```
char buffer[50];
strcpy(buffer, "The ");
strcat(buffer, variedinput);
strcat(buffer, " jumped over the fence.");
```

Is there some other function that allows me to do something like the following?

```
function(buffer, "The %s jumped over the fence.", variedinput)
```

Comment: sprintf(buffer,"",...)?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/?kw=sprintf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sprintf(buffer,"",...)`?
Write formatted data to string.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/?kw=sprintf

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is called `spnrintf`. I your code:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "The %s jumped over the fence", variedinput);
```

The rules for the format string and later arguments are the same as for `printf`. Of course, you must make sure `variedinput` actually points to a string in this example.

Comment: And note that snprintf's return value is the number of characters you *need*, so you should check that it isn't longer than the buffer and retry.